# Проблема с javascript tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Пытаюсь сделать скрипт, чтобы он каждые 5 минут нажимал на кнопку, но когда я переключаюсь со вкладки на другую он прекращает работу, как это можно пофиксить?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         EpicLoot AutoClaim
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1
// @description  EpicLoot AutoClaim
// @author       Arc W0rd3n)
// @match        https://epicloot.in/event
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    'use strict';
    const f = () => {
        document.querySelectorAll('#battle > div > div.game-container > div.game-gift     > div > div.game-gift__try > div.game-gift__take').forEach(i => i.click());
        window.setTimeout(f, 60000)
    };
    f();
})();
```

Comment: Во-первых, убедитесь что скрипт запустился, добавьте это `// run-at document-end` или если не заработает то: `// run-at document-idle` в мета теги. Во-вторых, убедитесь что у вас корректный `@match`, поменяйте его на это `// @match *://epicloot.in/event*` или же для того, чтобы он точно работал только на той странице которую вы указали, можно написать так: `// @include https?:\/\/epicloot\.in/event(\?.*)?`

Comment: скрипт работает, есть уведомление о нажатии на кнопку, но после перехода оно пропадает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот такой, даже после того как вы свернёте браузер скрипт всё равно будет работать.

```js
// Пример
const btns = document.getElementById('button');
let clickerCount = 0;

function click() {
  for (elem of btns.children) {
    elem.click();
  }
  console.log(++clickerCount);
}

setInterval(click, 1000);

/*
// Ваш код
const gifts = document.querySelectorAll('#battle > div > div.game-container > div.game-gift     > div > div.game-gift__try > div.game-gift__take');

function clickGift() {
  for (gift of gifts) {
    gift.click();
  }
}

setInterval(clickGift, 5500);

*/
```

```html
<div id='button'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</div>
```

Comment: не работает, как я понял оно не подходит для tampermonkey

Comment: пофиксил, но оно не работает как мне надо, просто выполняет определенное количество кликов

Comment: @t4mp3rm0nk3y если это брузерная игра то почему просто не запустить скрипт через F12?